# Redirect stripping the matched string - Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using .htaccess, I want to redirect all the pages which contains `--nocolor-` at the end of their url. I want redirect them to the same url without the match.

Example:
`https://www.test.com/products/test--nocolor-`
to
`https://www.test.com/products/test`

What I've tried is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (--nocolor-)
```

and that is working but I cannot get the right url while rewriting.
I've tried

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)(?=--nocolor-) /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)(?=--nocolor-) /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*(?=--nocolor-) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I always end up with $1 empty.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following .htaccess rules. Make sure to place these rules at top of your .htaccess rules.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.*)--nocolor-\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works thank you. Tell me if I understand: 
the group matched (.*) will be only this products/test because --nocolor- is outside the brackets right? Then for any url ^ redirect to /%1 which will be /products/test. Why do you place \s at the beginning and at the end?

Comment: @GiacomoScarpino, yes for `%1` you are right. For `\s` question that's because variable `THE_REQUEST` variable has spaces before and after uri value in it that's why I have used `\s` before and after actual matching. Kindly do let me know in case of any other queries are there.

Comment: Why use a RewriteCond to begin with? `RewriteRule (.*)--nocolor-$ /$1 [R=301,L]` alone should achieve the same thing.

Comment: @CBroe, yes I thought the same thing but then variable `THE_REQUEST` denotes original uri of call, so I thought to make use of it because in single call/hit/request it doesn't changes. But yes we can make use of only rewriterule too.